# How to change the tabbing behavior of Infragistics UltraTabbedMdiManager which opens the first tab always?

Tags: winforms, infragistics

We have used `UltraTabbedMdiManager`  of `Infragistics` in our WinForms application. We have one pane at the left side of the application and various forms are opened in the tabs using Infragistics control.

Let's say I have 3 different forms open in 3 tabs of the control. But 2nd form is visible at the moment i.e. 2nd form is selected by the user.

If user clicks in the left pane and starts tabbing (using `TAB` key on the keyboard), **I want the focus to be shifted to the tab/form which is already opened** i.e. 2nd tab. But this does not happen. Everytime the first tab/form is selected when user tabs (using TAB key) from left pane to the Infragistics control.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The UltraTabbedMdiManager doesn't control/affect the behavior of which form is activated as you tab through the controls.  If you remove the UltraTabbedMdiManager, you will see the same behavior with the child windows of your MDI application.  When reaching the last control on the MDI parent, you will always tab into the first MDI child form and when you reach the end of the controls on that child you will tab to the first control on that child form.